# Swift 2, Xcode 7.2 'NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

```
Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not save file data for image.png : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=263 "Failed to create PFFile with data: data is larger than 10MB." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create PFFile with data: data is larger than 10MB
```

Using www.heroku.com as an alternate parse.com.  It uses MonoLab database and I am trying to post an image to my database but it is returning the error that data is larger than 10MB.

How can I get it to post?  Is there something I can do?  Noobie swift programmer.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class PostImageViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var imageToPost: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var message: UITextField!

@IBAction func chooseImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    // ... import image
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    // ... when user has picked image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    imageToPost.image = image // set the imageToPost to the image selected in Library


}

@IBAction func postImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let post = PFObject(className: "Post")

    post["message"] = message.text
    post["userId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!


    // save image
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToPost.image!)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData!)

    post["imageFile"] = imageFile
    post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

        //

        if error == nil {

            print("Success")

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably resize and have the `imageData` smaller. A simpler approach could be:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost.image!, 0.1)
let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData!)
```